# AES128暗号化・復号化のswift3対応について

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

以下の暗号化・復号化メソッドをswift3対応させたのですが、
戻り値をStringに変換する際にクラッシュするようになりました。

swift2.2

```
func AES128Crypt(data data:NSData,  keyData:NSData, operation:Int) -> NSData? {

    let keyBytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(keyData.bytes)

    let dataLength = Int(data.length)
    let dataBytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)

    let cryptData: NSMutableData! = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    let cryptPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(cryptData.mutableBytes)
    let cryptLength = size_t(cryptData.length)

    let keyLength = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
    let algoritm: CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
    let options: CCOptions = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(CCOperation(operation), algoritm,
                              options,
                              keyBytes, keyLength,
                              nil,
                              dataBytes, dataLength,
                              cryptPointer, cryptLength,
                              &numBytesEncrypted)

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {

        cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

    } else {
        print("\(#line) Error: \(cryptStatus)")
    }

    return cryptData
}
```

swift3対応後

```
func AES128Crypt(data:Data,  keyData:Data, operation:Int) -> Data? {

    let keyBytes = (keyData as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: keyData.count)

    let dataLength = Int(data.count)
    let dataBytes = (data as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: data.count)

    let cryptData: NSMutableData! = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    //以下を変更
    let cryptInt = Int(bitPattern: cryptData.mutableBytes)
    guard let cryptPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(bitPattern: cryptInt) else {
        print("\(#line) Error: cryptPointer is nil")
        return nil
    }
    //変更終了
    let cryptLength = size_t(cryptData.length)

    let keyLength = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
    let algoritm: CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
    let options: CCOptions = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(CCOperation(operation), algoritm,
                              options,
                              keyBytes, keyLength,
                              nil,
                              dataBytes, dataLength,
                              cryptPointer, cryptLength,
                              &numBytesEncrypted)

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {

        cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

    } else {
        print("\(#line) Error: \(cryptStatus)")
    }

    return cryptData as Data?
}
```

エラー発生箇所

```
let encryptStr = String(data: encryptData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
```

エラーメッセージ

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
```

エラーが示す箇所

```
-> 0x7ef9e0 <+124>: trap
```

エラーが発生する原因は`String(data: encryptData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)`の戻り値がnilなのにアンラップした為なのですが、
戻り値が格納されている`encryptData`の中身はあるのに変換できない原因がわからないでいます。

またシミュレーターで動作確認を行っている際には気づかなかったので、
実機のみで発生すると思われます。

この場合、暗号化の処理が正しくないのかと思っていたのですが、
ネットを見ていると別の要因もあるという話もあったので、見当違いのことをしているのかと思い質問しました。
swift3の対応には間違いはあるでしょうか？

Comment: Swift2.2のコードが3.0の物になっていませんか？
また、暗号化後のバイナリデータをbase64ではなくutf8へ変換するのは無理があるように思います。以前は損失無く動いていたのでしょうか。

Comment: @takabosoft ご指摘ありがとうございます。swift3に自動変換した際のコードになっていたので、swift2.2のコードに修正しました。正しいデータを取得していたので、以前は問題なく動いていたはずなのですが・・・

Comment: 全く見当違いかもしれませんが、自分のアプリではDataとNSDataをブリッジさせて使うと謎のクラッシュが起こる事がありました（検証記事：http://qiita.com/takabosoft/items/f7eab4ef28753825251a　）もしかすると、NSDataを使わずにDataだけで暗号化部分を書けば症状が治まるかもわかりません。

Comment: あなたのコードには、`Data`やpointerの使い方に関してあまりお勧めできない書き方が含まれているので、最初はそのせいかもと思ったのですが、どうも、`let encryptStr = String(data: encryptData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!`の方が腑に落ちません。一般的にはデータを暗号化した結果は任意のバイト列であり、それを無理にUTF-8として解釈しようとすれば、変換できない→nilになる可能性は十分にあります。`AES128Crypt`を呼ぶところから、その結果を`String.init(data:encoding:)`に渡すまでの部分を(できればサンプルとして使える`data`, `keyData`を含めて)ご質問に追記していただけないでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

コメントに書いた「できればサンプル‌​として使える`data`, `keyData`を含めて」なんていう部分を難しく考えすぎると、すごく大変なことのように思えるかもしれませんので、「あまりお勧めできない書き方」を修正して、(あなたの「swift3対応後」のコードを見ずに)元の「swift2.2」のコードをSwift 3に書き直したものを示しておきます。

「実機のみで発生すると思われます」との記載がありましたので、Debug構成、Release構成の両方で試しましたが、問題なく動いているコードです。

```
func AES128Crypt(data: Data, keyData: Data, operation: Int) -> Data {

    let dataLength = data.count

    var cryptData = Data(count: dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    let cryptLength = cryptData.count

    let keyLength = kCCKeySizeAES128
    let algoritm = CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
    let options = CCOptions(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted: Int = 0

    let cryptStatus = keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {cryptPointer in
                CCCrypt(CCOperation(operation), algoritm,
                        options,
                        keyBytes, keyLength,
                        nil,
                        dataBytes, dataLength,
                        cryptPointer, cryptLength,
                        &numBytesEncrypted)
            }
        }
    }

    if cryptStatus == CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) {

        cryptData.count = numBytesEncrypted

    } else {
        print("\(#line) Error: \(cryptStatus)")
    }

    return cryptData
}
```

このコードでも同じ状況が発生するなら、`String.init(data:encoding:)`の使い方(それまでのいろいろな`data`の使い方)に問題がある可能性が高いですし、このコードに差し替えて問題が発生しなくなれば、`Data`, `NSData`の使い方に問題があったのだと思われます。

何か新情報があれば更新しますので、是非お試しの上ご連絡ください。